# How to display npm-debug.log in Jenkins build log?

Tags: node.js, logging, jenkins

When building with npm from within Jenkins, a npm-debug.log is created on disk with debug information. It's far more convenient to have this debug information in Jenkins' build log. I could achieve this by redirecting the npm-debug.log to stdout, but I seem unable to find a way to do that. Any hints or tips? The whole npm-debug.log seems to be hardcoded for some strange reason.

Comment: Did you try to run it with: debug-logger.  e.g:  npm install debug-logger

Comment: This outputs all error during the install of debug-logger to the npm-debug.log. I want to catch all error in Jenkins, to avoid giving developers access to the CI server to check the logs in de workspace. There must be a way to redirect debug logging from the get-go to stdout?

Comment: an ugly way will be to use cat(Linux)  or type(Windows) on the log file.

Comment: I still have this usecase. Did anyone figure out a solution to this problem?